# How to find div with specific class with bs4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a specific class of divs from an HTML document using bs4. However, when I use the find_all() method, I do not get back the divs that I want despite the fact that I can see those divs when I print out the text of the soup object I have.

I'm looking for a div like this [from this website](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/shooting/2010)

```
<div style="top:128px;left:58px;" tip="Nov 20, 2009, OKC vs WAS<br>4th Qtr, 11:02 remaining<br>Made 2-pointer from 20 ft<br>OKC now leads 97-86" class="tooltip make">&#9679;</div>
```

to do this I search the soup object

```
shots = soup.find_all("div", _class="tooltip make")
```

However, the returning `shots` array is empty

The divs are loaded through JS on the website, however even when I used selenium to render the page this same problem occurred. Additionally I've printed out the soup document I recive when just making the HTTP request and I can see the divs I'm looking for when I print it out.

This one has had me stuck for a bit so I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You *forgot* to ask your question. Please (re)read [ask] and make sure you have a [mre].

Comment: _"and I can see the divs I'm looking for when I print it out"_ - can you really, though ...? All I am seeing in the HTML code returned by the server is an _HTML comment_  that contains those inside.

Comment: your code is incorrect. did you forget an `=` between shots and the rest of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section you are looking for is commented out, so easiest way would be uncomment the elements by replacement of `<!--` and `-->` from the response text:

```
requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/shooting/2010').text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')
```

Also check your selection and change the class parameter:

```
find_all("div", class_="tooltip make")
```

or use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
select('div.tooltip.make)
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/shooting/2010').text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')).find_all("div", class_="tooltip make")
soup
```